# Confusion regarding inflater.inflate Android documentation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm studying fragments from this link : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

There's a piece of code given as:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}
```

}

I was confused about the attachToRoot parameter so I looked up on Stack Overflow for some help and found good answers on similar problem. So what I understand is if you set it to true, the fragment gets attached to the activity's root layout, and derives its layoutparams from there. If it's false it would simply return the root of the inflated layout and acts like a standalone view for a fragment (deriving the layout params from the passed in container).

Now I read further down in the documentation regarding attachToRoot for the above example:

> A boolean indicating whether the inflated layout should be attached to
>   the ViewGroup (the second parameter) during inflation. (In this case,
>   this is false because the system is already inserting the inflated
>   layout into the container—passing true would create a redundant view
>   group in the final layout.)

I don't get the last parenthesis statement where it says that it should be false because we're already inserting the layout into the container. What does it mean that we're already inserting into the container without attachToRoot as true? If the parameter is true, how would the final layout have redundant view groups. An example to elaborate this part would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't usually answer my own questions, but after doing a bit more research for this, I thought that maybe this will help someone else. Although Marcin's answer is correct, but I'm just answering a bit more in detail.

As per code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
}
```

The second parameter *container* is a framelayout with id fragment_container that activity uses to add fragment to it's layout.

Now, if we dive deeper into inflate method of LayoutInflater class, this is the code (I'm just highlighting the relevant parts of code rather than the whole part) :

```
// The view that would be returned from this method.
View result = root;

// Temp is the root view that was found in the xml.                     
final View temp = createViewFromTag(root, name, attrs, false);
```

Firstly, it creates a temp view from the supplied root.

In case *attachToRoot is true*, it does this :

```
if (root != null && attachToRoot) {
    root.addView(temp, params);
}
```

It adds the temp view created above to the root view (i.e. container).

In case *attachToRoot* is false, it does this:

```
if (root == null || !attachToRoot) {
   result = temp;   
}
```

As quite evident, in case *attachToRoot is true*, it simply returns the root (fragment_container i.e the id activity uses to place the fragment inside it.) after adding the temp view to it (Root view in example_fragment in this case)).

In case *attachToRoot is false*, it simply returns the root of the fragment's xml, i.e. the container parameter is just used to get layoutParams for fragment's root view (since it doesn't have a root, so it needs params from somewhere).

The problem in case of true, arises in above example, because the return value is root (fragment_container with added view temp, and fragment_container by default has a parent already.). Now, if you try to do a fragment transaction, you're trying to add a child view fragment_container(*which already has a parent*  to another xml (framelayout that you defined to add the fragment to).

Due to this, Android throws the following exception:

```
if (child.getParent() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The specified child already has a parent. " + 
"You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.");
    }
```

Problem while setting it to true and returning is that the view returned already has a parent, so can't be used else where. Other way, you could make a separate view group inside onCreateView (maybe a LinearLayout), set the parameter to true, and return the view. Then it'll work fine because the viewgroup won't have an existing parent.

This is my understanding of the above problem, I might be wrong in which case I'd like any Android expert to correct this.

Comment: Brilliant Observation!

Comment: Thank you! This is really confusing... They should have named the parameters in a less confusing fashion. In my opinion they should rename the arguments to inflate(resource, parent, attachToParent) instead of inflate(resource, root, attachToRoot) because the latter is just vague and repetitively mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

It means that in case on `onCreateView()` returned `View` will be attached to container view anyway, so setting it to `true` in your `onCreateView()` would cause it to be added twice to container layout, which isn't what you usually want. And setting root view to not null and still have `attachToRoot` false allows inflated view to derive from root, w/o being added.

Comment: Hi Marcin, can you let me know any scenario where we'll set it to true? Any small example would be helpful.

Comment: For example you build your view from many layouts. you can then either inflate them separately and the do addView() by hand, or just setnthis flag to true and do not bother more.

Comment: @gauravjain does this all answers your question?

Comment: It partially does, but I didn't accept because the complete solution with reason was explained by my colleague, who's not on SO. So, I didn't accept any answer here.

Comment: Also please become familiar with this meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: Well you can say it's a bit short, or maybe it takes me some time to grasp these things. When I saw the source, I could really get what's going on under the hood, and what causes that redundancy and exception in final layout when that parameter is true. But yeah, as I said, I appreciate your answer because this was the only legit answer until Elitz wrote his one. Also, thanks for the above link, but it's not that I don't accept answers on any question.

Comment: I'm not here to fight, but most of those questions were not well written hence didn't get proper answers too which was a mistake on my part. Over time I've tried improving upon it to get good answers. No further arguments, I appreciate your answer but I won't accept. Yes, the community is welcomed to choose this as accepted answer, I won't judge anyone else opinion. Peace!

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
View v =getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, viewgroup);
```

and also this

```
View v =getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, null);
```

now if you call this for the first scenario

```
Log.v("testing",String.valueOf(v.getParent() == null));
```

you will get `false` as the output, but when you check that on the second line you will get `true`.

Simple understanding is if you specify a parent(ViewGroup) it is attached to it, but if you add the last parameter the you are telling the inflater to skip the attachment of the View so your returned View has no parent, but if you specify null, who's going to be attached to? NOBODY so the returned View has no parent, and also like you stated it derives layoutParameters for the View.

If you dont add the last parameter the View will have its parent as the Activity `View` and hence will be returned in your OncreateView having already a parent, before it will be added, which will cause some Exceptions as a View cannot have different daddies and the Fragment will not be able to manage the View itself.

*if add true return null from your oncreateView*

Answer (score -2):

The View that you return from onCreateView() method of a fragment, will be attached to the container of the fragment by the system. So the third parameter of inflate() method should be false in this case. If you set it to true then it will be attached to the root twice. So you should set it to false in this case.

Now, the inflated view derives its layout parameters from the second parameter of inflate() method not from the third boolean parameter.

Answer (score -2):

ok from android official documentation [Android documentation](http://[1]:%20http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> What is Fragment?

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

> How to Use Fragment in Activity?

A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments. However, while an activity is running (it is in the resumed lifecycle state), you can manipulate each fragment independently, such as add or remove them.

> What is Fragment Transaction

you can manipulate each fragment independently, such as add or remove them. When you perform such a fragment transaction, you can also add it to a back stack that's managed by the activity—each back stack entry in the activity is a record of the fragment transaction that occurred. The back stack allows the user to reverse a fragment transaction (navigate backwards), by pressing the Back button.

> How Fragment and Activity Interact with each other

When you add a fragment as a part of your activity layout, it lives in a ViewGroup inside the activity's view hierarchy and the fragment defines its own view layout. You can insert a fragment into your activity layout by declaring the fragment in the activity's layout file, as a  element, or from your application code by adding it to an existing ViewGroup.

> Fragment Lifecycle methods onCreateView()
>      onCreate()
>      onPause()

And your question is

> What does it mean that we're already inserting into the container without attachToRoot as true? If the parameter is true, how would the final layout have redundant view groups

and here is answar
suppose you have added  already in your activity layout then you do not' need to make last parameter to true.because each time you perform add or remove of fragment their is a fragment transaction.
However if you have not added already a fragment in your layout then you can set it to true.

read this in doc

> You can insert a fragment into your activity layout by declaring the fragment in the activity's layout file, as a  element, or from your application code by adding it to an existing ViewGroup. However, a fragment is not required to be a part of the activity layout; you may also use a fragment without its own UI as an invisible worker for the activity.

all fragment transaction are added on activity back stack

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand my question. It's not related to how I can add fragment to activity (statically or dynamically). That's pretty clear, the problem is in attachToRoot parameter. As per your answer for dynamic addition of fragment to activity, we should set it to true, which isn't quite right (It throws an exception). Anyways I appreciate your effort and time.