# what is is the difference between inflating layout methods and what are these parameters for

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-inflate

I found out that you can inflate Layout in these 3 ways. But cannot get the use of 2nd and 3rd parameters in respective statements. What is the ViewGroup and attachedToroot parameters for?

First use for outside an Activity:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.myNewInflatedLayout, ViewGroup);
 View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.myNewInflatedLayout, ViewGroup, attachedToroot);

Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById( R.id.myButton );
```

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854605/confusion-regarding-inflater-inflate-android-documentation

Comment: @gauravjain my question is not only second part but also about adding viewGroup or not adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your doubts regarding the use of 2nd parameter and the third parameter.

The second parameter is a ViewGroup, which is described in the docs as :

> public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)
>
> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource. Throws InflateException if there is an error.
>
> **root**  Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.
>
> Returns
>
> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is
>   the root View; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file.

Based on this, there are 2 possibilities that I see :

1. You set viewgroup as null. In this case, your layout will be inflated in the activity but the root view of that inflated hierarchy would be the root of the xml file. So if your xml has a relative layout or any other layout as the root element, that would become the root of your inflated hierarchy. You would have something like :

   `<xml>  // Whatever is the root of this xml, is your root for the inflated hierarchy.`
2. In case you set the viewgroup to something else, that would become the root of the inflated hierarchy. So, effectively you would have something like this : 

   `<Your Viewgroup>
    <Your xml>
   </Your Viewgroup>`

   As evident here, in this case, your specified viewgroup will be the parent of the inflated hierarchy. So I think it entirely depends on your requirement.

Regarding the third parameter : [Confusion regarding inflater.inflate Android documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854605/confusion-regarding-inflater-inflate-android-documentation)

You can read my answer on this link, to get to know more about it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: ok thanks It's use full. but i still wont get the third parameter and what is it for? i mean "attachedToroot"

Comment: Did you follow the link I gave because I think I explained it quite clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the developer.android.com for reference, you will see four public methods.

[image: inflate]

Most used two are the ones you wrote in your question.

`inflater.inflate( R.layout.myNewInflatedLayout, ViewGroup);`

`inflater.inflate( R.layout.myNewInflatedLayout, ViewGroup,
 attachedToroot);`

Here is an excerpt from really great [article](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/) about layout inflations.

> The first parameter points to the layout resource you want to inflate.
>   The second parameter is the root view of the hierarchy you are
>   inflating the resource to attach to. When the third parameter is
>   present, it governs whether or not the inflated view is attached to
>   the supplied root after inflation.

I suggest you to read it till the end. Hope this help. :)

Comment: I use null for second parameter but i don't have any problem of showing in my activity. should I attach to my activity by passing proper viewGroup? is it necessary? what is benefits of using that?

Comment: @Kenji I shared you the whole article. You gotta read the whole article. Everything is there. This is answered.